# Symmetrically splitting an octagon into quadrilaterals

Tags: symmetry, polygons

I'm wondering whether it is possible to split an octagon into a finite number of quadrilaterals, such that the result is symmetric from all 8 directions (sides or points). There is one condition — any new points that are created must be on the inside of the octagon (i.e. no new points on the edges of the octagon).

The figure below illustrates 4 of my attempts. Most of them (the $1^{st}$, $2^{nd}$ and $4^{th}$) are not symmetric from all 8 directions, and are therefore no valid solution. The $3^{rd}$ one is symmetric, but creates points on the edges.

[image]

I'm curious how one could prove that there is (or isn't) a solution to such a problem?

Comment: I would like to know your motivation. I agree that the problem is interesting.

Comment: @user5335 Well, I have a polygonal mesh which almost exclusively consists of quadrilaterals, except for a few octagons — I'd like to end up with a mesh consisting of only quads. Simply applying something like a Catmull-Clark subdivision algorithm creates too many new quads, so I'd like to solve this problem with a local approach.

Comment: How does the third attempt "create" points on the edges? We have to be able to us the vertices.

Comment: @robjohn The third attempt (i.e. the fourth picture) bisects all edges of the octagon, therefore adding new vertices on its edges.

Comment: The fourth picture also creates triangles rather than quadrilaterals. If that isn't a problem, just add one point in the centre and join to each vertex.

Comment: @Ailurus: oh, I misread *third* to mean third. I see that the fourth adds points on the edges. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want rotational symmetry of degree 8. (If what you want is reflection along the 4 different axis, then let me know.) Such a configuration is not possible.

Recall that the angles in a octagon sum to $180^\circ \times 6$, and the angles in a quadrilateral sum to $180^\circ \times 2 $.

Since we can only add internal points, note that adding a point would increase the sum of angles by $360^\circ$. If we add a point that is not in the center, then by rotational symmetry, we must add all 8 symmetric points.

By double counting the angles, this shows that we must have $8k+3$ or $8k+4$ quadrilaterals.

However, by rotational symmetry of the figure, there must be $8l$ of $8l+1$ quadrilaterals.

---

Comment: Thanks, that's a good argument! However, rotational symmetry of degree 8 might be a little too restrictive. It is sufficient if it is symmetric along the horizontal, vertical and the two diagonal axes (the attempt depicted in the fifth picture is based on this, a square in an octagon).

Comment: I mentioned this because it is not clear what you mean in your question. That example you gave does not have horizontal symmetry, or any of the diagonal axis.

Comment: Indeed, that one only has vertical symmetry. I couldn't figure out how to end up with more axes of symmetry...

Comment: So is there a method to do it with symmetry/reflection along the 4 axes?